# Writing a lexer for a new programming language in python

Tags: python, programming-languages, lexer

I have no idea how/where to start. I'm supposed to be using python, and more specifically, the ply library. So far, all I've done in create a list of tokens that will be part of the language. That list is given below:

```py
tokens = (
                                                         # OPERATORS #
    'PLUS' ,        # +
    'MINUS' ,       # -
    'MULTIPLY',     # *
    'DIVIDE',       # /
    'MODULO',       # %


    'NOT',          # ~
    'EQUALS',       # =

                                                         # COMPARATORS #
    'LT',           # <
    'GT',           # >
    'LTE',          # <=
    'GTE',          # >=
    'DOUBLEEQUAL',  # ==
    'NE',           # #


    'AND',          # &
    'OR',           # |
                                                    # CONDITIONS AND LOOPS #    

    'IF',           # if
    'ELSE',         # else
    'ELSEIF',       # elseif
    'WHILE',        # while
    'FOR',          # for
#   'DOWHILE',      # haven't thought about this yet
                                                          # BRACKETS #

    'LPAREN',       # (
    'RPAREN',       # )
    'LBRACE',       # [
    'RBRACE',       # ]
    'BLOCKSTART',   # {
    'BLOCKEND',     # }
                                                        # IDENTIFIERS #

    'INTEGER',      # int
    'DOUBLE',       # dbl
    'STRING',       # str
    'CHAR',         # char

    'SEMICOLON',    # ;
    'DOT',          # .
    'COMMA',        # ,
    'QUOTES',       # '
    'DOUBLEQUOTES', # "
    'COMMENTLINE',  # --

    'RETURN',       # return

)
```

I've obviously got a long way to go, seeing as I also need to write a parser and an interpreter.

I've got a few questions:

1. How do I use the ply library?
2. Is this a good start, and if so, what do I go from this?
3. Are there any resources I can use to help me with this.

I've tried googling stuff on writing new programming languages, but I haven't yet found anything satisfactory

Comment: For starting, that is a tuple not a list.

Answer (score 13):

> How do I use the ply library?

Assuming that you already have Ply installed, you should start with exploring the tutorials on the [official Ply website](http://www.dabeaz.com/ply/ply.html#ply_nn9). They are well written and easy to follow.

> Is this a good start, and if so, what do I go from this?

Ply requires token definitions to begin with. You have already done that. However, the complexities increase when your lexer has to differentiate between say a string like "forget" and a reserved keyword like `for`. The library provides good support for variable precedence to resolve grammar ambiguity. This can be as easy as defining the precedence as tuples:

```
precedence = (
 ('left', 'STRING', 'KEYWORD'),
 ('left', 'MULTIPLY', 'DIVIDE')
 )
```

However, I recommend you should read more about [lexers and yacc](http://shop.oreilly.com/product/9781565920002.do) before deep diving into the more advanced features like **expressions** and **precedence** in Ply. For a start, you should build a simple numerical lexer that successfully parses integers, operators and bracket symbols. I've reduced the token definition to suit this purpose. The following example has been modified from the official tutorials.

- **Library import & Token definition**:

  ```
  import ply.lex as lex #library import
  # List of token names.   This is always required
  tokens = [
                                                       # OPERATORS #
  'PLUS' ,        # +
  'MINUS' ,       # -
  'MULTIPLY',     # *
  'DIVIDE',       # /
  'MODULO',       # %


  'NOT',          # ~
  'EQUALS',       # =

                                                       # COMPARATORS #
  'LT',           # <
  'GT',           # >
  'LTE',          # <=
  'GTE',          # >=
  'DOUBLEEQUAL',  # ==
  'NE',           # !=
  'AND',          # &
  'OR' ,          # |                                                
                                                        # BRACKETS #

  'LPAREN',       # (
  'RPAREN',       # )
  'LBRACE',       # [
  'RBRACE',       # ]
  'BLOCKSTART',   # {
  'BLOCKEND',     # }
                                                      # DATA TYPES#

  'INTEGER',      # int
  'FLOAT',       # dbl

  'COMMENT',  # --

  ]
  ```
- **Define regular expression rules for simple tokens**: Ply uses the `re` Python library to find regex matches for tokenization. Each token requires a regex definition. We first define regex definitions for simple tokens. Each rule declaration begins with the special prefix `t_` to indicate that it defines a token.

  ```
  # Regular expression rules for simple tokens

  t_PLUS    = r'\+'
  t_MINUS   = r'-'
  t_MULTIPLY   = r'\*'
  t_DIVIDE  = r'/'
  t_MODULO = r'%'
  t_LPAREN  = r'\('
  t_RPAREN  = r'\)'
  t_LBRACE = r'\['
  t_RBRACE = r'\]'
  t_BLOCKSTART = r'\{'
  t_BLOCKEND = r'\}'
  t_NOT = r'\~'
  t_EQUALS = r'\='
  t_GT = r'\>'
  t_LT = r'\<'
  t_LTE = r'\<\='
  t_GTE = r'\>\='
  t_DOUBLEEQUAL = r'\=\='
  t_NE = r'\!\='
  t_AND = r'\&'
  t_OR = r'\|'
  t_COMMENT = r'\#.*'            
  t_ignore  = ' \t' ignore spaces and tabs
  ```
- **Define regular expression rules for more complex tokens** like data types such as int, float and newline characters to track line numbers. You will notice that these definitions are quite similar to the above.

  ```
  #Rules for INTEGER and FLOAT tokens
  def t_INTEGER(t):
      r'\d+'
      t.value = int(t.value)    
      return t

  def t_FLOAT(t):
      r'(\d*\.\d+)|(\d+\.\d*)'
      t.value = float(t.value)
      return t        

  # Define a rule so we can track line numbers
  def t_newline(t):
      r'\n+'
      t.lexer.lineno += len(t.value)
  ```
- **Add some error handling for invalid characters**:

  ```
  # Error handling rule
  def t_error(t):
      print("Illegal character '%s'" % t.value[0])
      t.lexer.skip(1)
  ```
- **Build the lexer**:

  ```
  lexer = lex.lex()
  ```
- **Test the lexer with some input data, tokenize and print tokens**:

  ```
  data = '''
  [25/(3*40) + {300-20} -16.5]
  {(300-250)<(400-500)}
  20 & 30 | 50
  # This is a comment
  '''

  # Give the lexer some input
  lexer.input(data)

  # Tokenize
  for tok in lexer:
      print(tok)
  ```

You can add this example code to a Python script file like `new_lexer.py` and run it like `python new_lexer.py`. You should get the following output. Note that the input data consisted of newline(`'\n'`) characters that were successfully ignored in the output.

```
    #Output
    LexToken(LBRACE,'[',2,1)
    LexToken(INTEGER,25,2,2)
    LexToken(DIVIDE,'/',2,4)
    LexToken(LPAREN,'(',2,5)
    LexToken(INTEGER,3,2,6)
    LexToken(MULTIPLY,'*',2,7)
    LexToken(INTEGER,40,2,8)
    LexToken(RPAREN,')',2,10)
    LexToken(PLUS,'+',2,12)
    LexToken(BLOCKSTART,'{',2,14)
    LexToken(INTEGER,300,2,15)
    LexToken(MINUS,'-',2,18)
    LexToken(INTEGER,20,2,19)
    LexToken(BLOCKEND,'}',2,21)
    LexToken(MINUS,'-',2,23)
    LexToken(INTEGER,16,2,24)
    LexToken(FLOAT,0.5,2,26)
    LexToken(RBRACE,']',2,28)
    LexToken(BLOCKSTART,'{',3,30)
    LexToken(LPAREN,'(',3,31)
    LexToken(INTEGER,300,3,32)
    LexToken(MINUS,'-',3,35)
    LexToken(INTEGER,250,3,36)
    LexToken(RPAREN,')',3,39)
    LexToken(LT,'<',3,40)
    LexToken(LPAREN,'(',3,41)
    LexToken(INTEGER,400,3,42)
    LexToken(MINUS,'-',3,45)
    LexToken(INTEGER,500,3,46)
    LexToken(RPAREN,')',3,49)
    LexToken(BLOCKEND,'}',3,50)
    LexToken(INTEGER,20,4,52)
    LexToken(AND,'&',4,55)
    LexToken(INTEGER,30,4,57)
    LexToken(OR,'|',4,60)
    LexToken(INTEGER,50,4,62)
    LexToken(COMMENT,'# This is a comment',5,65)
```

There are many other features you can make use of. For instance, debugging can be enabled with `lex.lex(debug=True)`. The official tutorials provide more detailed information around these features.

I hope this helps to get you started. You can extend the code further to include reserved keywords like `if`, `while` and string identification with `STRING`, character identification with `CHAR`. The tutorials cover the implementation of reserved words by defining a key-value dictionary mapping like this:

```
    reserved = {
    'if' : 'IF',
    'then' : 'THEN',
    'else' : 'ELSE',
    'while' : 'WHILE',
    ...
    }
```

extending the tokens list further by defining the reserved token `type` as `'ID'` and including the `reserved` dict values: `tokens.append('ID')` and `tokens = tokens + list(reserved.values())`. Then, add a definition for `t_ID` as above.

> Are there any resources I can use to help me with this.

There are many resources available to learn about lexers, parsers and compilers. You should start with a good book that covers the theory and implementation. There are many books available that cover these topics. I liked this [one](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/012088478X). [Here's](https://www.jayconrod.com/posts/37/a-simple-interpreter-from-scratch-in-python-part-1) another resource that may help. If you'd like to explore similar Python libraries or resources, this [SO answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36953/resources-for-lexing-tokenising-and-parsing-in-python) may help.