# How to get semicolons except in parentheses with regex

Tags: python, regex

For the following *C source code* piece:

```
for (j=0; j<len; j++) a = (s) + (4); test = 5;
```

I want to insert `\n` after semicolons `;` except in parenthesis using python code regex module.

For the following  *C source code* piece:

```
for (j=0; j<(len); (j++)) a = (s) + (4); test = 5;
```

The regex `;(?![^(]*\))` works but not on the *first piece of code*.

Comment: `(?<={)(.*?)(;)` would work. https://regex101.com/r/OBKJCr/1

Comment: `;(?!.*\))` https://regex101.com/r/SvJAFP/1

Comment: MonkeyZeus - thanks but this not work. I just want to get semicolons and don't use bracket

Comment: Jacek Rojek - thanks It works.

Comment: @aria No, that [does not work](https://regex101.com/r/SvJAFP/2).

Comment: @aria Well good luck to you then because regex can't count so you have no way of tracking whether a parenthesis has closed or not.

Comment: Wiktor Stribiżew - yes you right but it's work -> ;(?![^\/\/]*\))

Comment: I would recommend researching the answers to this question:  https://stackoverflow.com/q/36953/816536

Comment: So you have tagged "python" because that is how you are trying to solve the issue.  However, from the sample line, you are dealing with, it looks like some C language variant.  And I assume the underlying issue you are looking at is that "test = 5" looks like it is part of the "for" loop, but really isn't if you look closely.  Perhaps you are trying to fix lintish errors or something.  Most IDEs offer this kind of formatting per various standards.  I recommend you let the IDE do it instead of writing a Python program.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use a custom [replacement function](https://docs.python.org/3.8/library/re.html#re.sub):

> `re.sub(pattern, repl, string, count=0, flags=0)`
>   ...
>   If `repl` is a function, it is called for every non-overlapping occurrence of `pattern`.

The function `repl` is called for every occurrence of a single `;` *and* for parenthesized expressions. Since `re.sub` does not find overlapping sequences, the very first opening parenthesis will trigger a full match all the way up to the last closing parenthesis.

```py
import re

def repl(m):
    contents = m.group(1)
    if '(' in contents:
        return contents
    return ';\n'

str1 = 'for (j=0; j<len; j++) a = (s) + (4); test = 5;'
str2 = 'for (j=0; j<(len); (j++)) a = (s) + (4); test = 5;'

print (re.sub (r'(;\s*|\(.*\))', repl, str1))
print (re.sub (r'(;\s*|\(.*\))', repl, str2))
```

Result:

```c
for (j=0; j<len; j++) a = (s) + (4);
test = 5;

for (j=0; j<(len); (j++)) a = (s) + (4);
test = 5;
```

Mission accomplished, for your (very little) sample data.

***But wait!***

A small – but valid – change in one of the examples

```
str1 = 'for (j=0; j<len; j++) test = 5; a = (s) + (4);'
```

breaks this with a wrong output:

```
for (j=0; j<len; j++) test = 5; a = (s) + (4);
```

There is no way around it, you need a *state machine* instead:

```py
def state_match (text):
    parentheses = 0
    drop_space = False
    result = ''
    for character in text:
        if character == '(':
            parentheses += 1
            result += '('
        elif character == ')':
            parentheses -= 1
            result += ')'
        elif character == ' ':
            if not drop_space:
                result += ' '
            drop_space = False
        elif character == ';':
            if parentheses:
                result += character
            else:
                result += ';\n'
                drop_space = True
        else:
            result += character
    return result

str1 = 'for (j=0; j<len; j++) a = (s) + (4); test = 5;'
str2 = 'for (j=0; j<(len); (j++)) a = (s) + (4); test = 5;'
str3 = 'for (j=0; j<len; j++) test = 5; a = (s) + (4);'

print (state_match(str1))
print (state_match(str2))
print (state_match(str3))
```

results correctly in:

```c
for (j=0; j<len; j++) a = (s) + (4);
test = 5;

for (j=0; j<(len); (j++)) a = (s) + (4);
test = 5;

for (j=0; j<len; j++) test = 5;
a = (s) + (4);
```

Answer (score 2):

You need to count opened and closed brackets for each regex match and only insert the newline, if there are more openend than closed brackets. This is done in replacement() which is called on each match of the regex. The regex searches for "(" and ")" just for counting, and for ";" to leave it or insert newline

```
import re

def replacement(matched_list):
    global bracket_count
    matched_char=matched_list.group(1)
    if "(" in matched_char:
        bracket_count += 1
        # don't replace, just return what was found
        return matched_char 
    elif ")" in matched_char:
        bracket_count -= 1
        # don't replace, just return what was found
        return matched_char 
    elif ";" in matched_char:
        # if we're inside brackets, insert \n
        if bracket_count == 0:
            return ';\n'
        # if not, leave it intact
        else:
            return ';'

# example 1
bracket_count=0
code="for (j=0; j<len; j++) a = (s) + (4); test = 5;"
new_code = re.sub('([();] ?)', replacement, code)
print(code)
print(new_code)

# example 2
bracket_count=0
code="for (j=0; j<(len); (j++)) a = (s) + (4); test = 5;"
new_code = re.sub('([();])', replacement, code)
print(code)
print(new_code)

# example 3
bracket_count=0
code="for (j=0; j<len; j++) test = 5; a = (s) + (4);"
new_code = re.sub('([();])', replacement, code)
print(code)
print(new_code)
```

Result:

```
for (j=0; j<len; j++) a = (s) + (4); test = 5;
for (j=0; j<len; j++) a = (s) + (4);
test = 5;

for (j=0; j<(len); (j++)) a = (s) + (4); test = 5;
for (j=0; j<(len); (j++)) a = (s) + (4);
test = 5;
```

Comment: I would remove all the *return* statements from the *if* content, instead do a single `return matched_char` at the end of `replacement`. Make an exception of `bracket_count == 0` since that does change the input. https://repl.it/repls/VivaciousRepulsivePyramid

Comment: @3limin4t0r: nope, the " single 'return matched_char' at the end of replacement" wouldn't remove the space after the ; as the "return ';'" does.

Comment: *"I want to insert `\n` after semicolons `;` except in parenthesis using python code regex module."* The question doesn't say anything about removing spaces. Those are just assumptions.